# print variable's value contain variable is it possible in twig? like php we have used $$ to print variable value?

Tags: twig

i have user object that contain all user fields.

and listFields array that have ["user.id", "user.email","user.gender"].
so variables in string.

i want to loop listFields and print it's original value from user object

currently user.id user.email print on screen.

i want to print it's value in screen.

have any solution for this! or it is possible?

**Mycode**

```
{% for fieldName in listFields %}
    <td>
        {{ fieldName }}                                               
    </td>                         
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print dynamic variables u can make use of the function `attribute`:

```
{% set user_fields = [ 'user.id', 'user.email', 'user.gender', 'alice.email', 'bob.id', 'bob.foo', ] %}

{% for field in user_fields %}
     {{ attribute(attribute(_context, (field|split('.'))[0])|default([]), (field|split('.'))[1])|default(null) }}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/566zhp)

---

```
array:3 [▼
  "user" => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 42
    "email" => "user@example.com"
    "gender" => 0
  ]
  "bob" => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "email" => "bob@example.com"
    "gender" => 0
  ]
  "alice" => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 100
    "email" => "alice@example.com"
    "gender" => 1
  ]
]
```

Comment: PEREFECT ONE! @DarkBee Thanks